# Insertar un valor definido despues de una busqueda utilizando bind param

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola a todos soy nuevo en esto, quiero agregar una inserción dentro de esta consulta que ya funciona, agregue una columna llamada paid_type en la que guardare un varchar 'C' pero desconozco como agregarlo, lo intenté de varias formas y no funcionó, serian tan amables de indicarme como agregar esa inserción

```
$insert_query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO historical_credits (id_student, credits_paid)
    SELECT id_student, ?
    FROM students
    WHERE student_qr = ?");
$insert_query->bind_param("is", $_POST['credits'], $_POST['studentqr']);
$insert_query->execute();
```

Comment: Tu `bind param` tiene 2 opciones pero le pasas 3, que es lo que quieres agregar exactamente, ese "is" para qué es?

Answer (score 0):

Analizando tu actual consulta lo que se interpreta es que:

1. Quieres encontrar en la tabla `students` el valor del `id_student` cuyo `student_qr` es igual al valor de `$_POST['studentqr']`
2. Insertar en `historical_credits` el valor del `id_student` encontrado y el valor de `$_POST['credits']`. El cual, analizando el código, va insertado **en bruto**, porque no se usa como criterio de nada.

Si la interpretación es otra, debes aclararlo, en el código y/o en la pregunta.

Si es eso, es mucho más simple de lo que estás haciendo aquí. Traslada a la consulta de inserción el valor de `$_POST['credits']` y deja en la sub-consulta el valor que necesitas de la tabla. Tu error es estar metiendo en el `SELECT` ese valor a mano, el cual no tiene nada que ve con la sub-consulta del `SELECT`.

La instrucción quedaría así (la pongo indentada, para que la entiendas mejor):

```
INSERT INTO historical_credits 
    (
      id_student, 
      credits_paid
    ) VALUES (
      (SELECT 
          id_student 
       FROM students
          WHERE student_qr = ? -- marcador para $_POST['studentqr']
          LIMIT 1), -- sub-consulta que trae el valor de id_student
      ? -- marcador para $_POST['credits']
    );
```

En el código quedaría así:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO historical_credits 
        (
          id_student, 
          credits_paid
        ) VALUES (
          (SELECT 
              id_student 
           FROM students
              WHERE student_qr = ?
              LIMIT 1), 
          ?
        )";
$insert_query = $con->prepare($sql);
/*
   NÓTESE que cambia el orden de los parámetros
   porque en $sql el primer marcador es para $_POST['studentqr']
   y el segundo marcador es para $_POST['credits']
   Cambia igualmente el tipo de dato a "si"
   Ten en cuenta que esto significa que:
    - la columna student_qr es de tipo string
    - la columna credits_paid es de tipo integer
   Si no es así, pon los marcadores "s"  e "i"
   según sea cada tipo de dato de esas columnas
*/              
$insert_query->bind_param("si",$_POST['studentqr'],$_POST['credits']);
$insert_query->execute();
```